# ASP.NET MVC 4 : open or save json file in IE7

Tags: json

While submitting a page, data is created in a json file and submitted.
It works fine in all browsers except IE7.
Really don't knw what's the issue.
Tried changing the MIME type

result = Json(model, "text/x-json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

result = Json(model, "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

result = Json(model, "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Included json2.js file ALSO, but doesn't redirect to Success page.

But it didn't work.

What I want is, it should redirect to Success page.. instead of asking me to open or save the json file.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support JSON stringifying out of the box.  Had a similar issue with one of my projects.

Grab Douglas Crockford's JSON library, include it and you should be good.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

json2.js is the file you need.

Comment: I included json2.js file in my web page.. but it didn't budge. <br /> Once included, it is able to recognize the json object. But fails to redirect to success page. All the latest browsers like Firefox 3.5+, IE 8+, Chrome, Safari 4+ etc. have built-in JSON capability.

Comment: Why don't you post the code that redirects to the success page?

Comment: {"SurveyQuestionList":null,"CurrentPerson":{"Citizenship":"","CollegeWebSearch":"","CreatedBy":0,"DateCreated":"\/Date(1358942807239)\/","DateUpdated":"\/Date(1358942807239)\/","DOB":"\/Date(1358942821742)\/","Email":"tr@tr.y","FirstName":"tr","GraduationYear":null,"HS_ID":"","InternetUse":"","IsActive":true,"LastName":"tr","MI":null,"PersonID":905707555,"PersonTypeID":0,"PreferedName":"","SequenceNumber":"","Sex":"M","RedirectUrl":"/Web/SignUpThankYou"}

Comment: I want to see the SignUpThankYou page in IE7

Comment: Nope, the bit that redirects to the success page.  You say the JSON object is correctly being interpreted now, so the issue must lie in your redirect code.  Please amend your question to include it.

Comment: [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewRegistration(LiteRegistrationLoginViewModel model)
    {
        ActionResult result = View(ViewNames.Index);
 try
 {
  // some logic to append details into result
 }
 catch(Exception ex){}

 result = Json(model);

        return result;
    }

Comment: hey, I checked in HttpWatch.. compared value of JSON object in IE7 and IE10. In IE7, it is interpreting it as [object Object],   whereas in IE10, it is interpreting as [object JSON].